# Geolocator and accuracy in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, windows-phone-8

I have a few questions about `Geolocator` and property `DesiredAccuracy`.

I have the method `GetMyPosition`:

```
public async Task<Geoposition> GetMyPosition()
            {
                Geoposition myGeoposition = null;
                Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
                myGeolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
                try
                {
                    myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
                    return myGeoposition;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Can't get the position");

                        });
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

1) Why

```
Geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;    
Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

always return `Geoposition.Coordinate.PositionSource = Cellular` with accuracy 400 - 1600 m (on device Nokia Lumia 520)?

2) Under what settings I can get a high accuracy (50 - 100 m) and `PositionSource = Satellite`?

3) If I have the loaded maps on my device and I activated the airplane mode on the device, then code

```
 Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
    myGeolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
    try
    {
         myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
         return myGeoposition;
    }
```

will work? Without a celluar, only a satellite?

4) How strong is the precision of coordinates depends on the device?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431814%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> Although the Location Service uses multiple sources of location information, and any of the sources may not be available at any given time (for example, no GPS satellites or cell phone towers may be accessible), the native code layer handles the work of evaluating the available data and choosing the best set of sources. All your application needs to do is to choose between high accuracy or the default, power-optimized setting. You can set this value when you initialize the main Location Service class, GeoCoordinateWatcher.
>
> C#
>
> `GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);`

So it seems like you can't control which source is used but rather the available source will be used based on the specified position accuracy on `GeoCoordinateWatcher`. Try initializing a `GeoCoordinateWatcher` with high accuracy and see what happens

```cs
var geoWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I would like to use the new geolocation API. In particular object Geolocator. I'll try  GeoCoordinateWatcher bit later and write about the results.

Comment: This problem of the device (Nokia Lumia 520) on other devices (HTC 8x), it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
myGeolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 20;
...
```

to explicitly state how accurate you want the location to be which would allow the device to manage its power a little better but whether you get close to that accuracy with your result depends on the quality of the location the device can get. If you're inside a building for example you're not going to get something that accurate without connecting to WIFI